# How to manage inventory: add, remove, modify/update , search, and print

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except, inventory-management

sorry if this is not presented well. This is my first time ever using StackOverflow. I'm trying to create this to keep track of inventory. I do not know how to utilize try-excepts. Additionally, I don't know what else is going wrong. Thanks for any and all help !

data handler:

```
import os

class DataHandler():

    def __init__(self, filename, datadict = {}):
        self.filename = filename
        self.datadict = datadict

    def readData(self):  # returns dictionary

        try:
            fileobj = open(self.filename,'r')
            datastr = fileobj.read()
            fileobj.close()
# return dictionary read from file or null dictionary
            if datastr != '':
                return eval(datastr)
            else:
                return self.datadict

        except FileNotFoundError:
            return self.datadict  # null dictionary

    def writeData(self, datadict):    # must pass dictionary

        fileobj = open(self.filename,'w')
        fileobj.write(str(datadict))
        fileobj.close()
```

separate file:

```
import DataHandler as DH

       def menuDisplay():
    print("="*40)
    print("1 - Add inventory item")
    print("2 - Modify inventory item")
    print("3 - Delete inventory item")
    print("4 - Print inventory list")
    print("5 - Exit program")
    print("="*40)
    selection = input("\nPlease enter menu choice: ")
    if selection < "1" and selection > "5":
        input("Invalid selection, please enter 1 - 5")
        menuDisplay()
    else:
        return int(selection)
        def addItem(invDict,dh):
    itemdesc = input("Item Description: ")
    itemqty = int(input("Qty: "))
    if len(invDict) > 0:
        nextKey = sorted(invDict.keys())[-1]+1
    else:
        nextKey = 1
    invDict[nextKey]=[itemdesc,itemqty]
    dh.writeData(invDict)

        def printInv(invDict):
        print("{:<10}{:20}{:6}".format("Item #", "Description", "Qty",))
        for dkey, lvalue in invDict.items():
            print("{:<10}{:20}{:6d}".format(str(dkey), lvalue[0],lvalue[1], lvalue[2]))

       def delItem(invDict,dh):
    itemnum = input("Please enter item to delete: ")
    del invDict[int(itemnum)]
    dh.writeData(invDict)
    # complete error checking

      def modItem(invDict,dh):
    itemnum = input("Please enter item to modify: ")
    newqty = input("Please enter the new quantity: ")
    invDict[int(itemnum)][1] = int(newqty)

    dh = DH.DataHandler("inventory.txt")
    invDict = dh.readData()

    selection = 0
    while selection != 5:
    selection = menuDisplay()

    if selection == 1:
        addItem(invDict,dh)
    elif selection == 2:
        modItem(invDict,dh)
    elif selection == 3:
        delItem(invDict,dh)
    elif selection == 4:
        printInv(invDict)
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail of what you need help with?

Comment: Function and variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Use context managers to handle files. Having a dictionary as a default value is probably a terrible idea. You’re comparing strings which contain numbers using `<` and `>`, this won’t behave the way you want it to. For example, did you know that `'10' < '5'`?

Comment: The formatting of the code in your post is off, making this a bit more difficult.

Comment: first: code has wrong indentations - correct it. Second: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use module `json` instead of `eval()`. Or see module `pickle`.